# WooCommerce hook - Get trigger

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm hooking the `woocommerce_product_set_stock` hook. Is there a way for me to find out whether it was triggered by a new order or, in general, to get the source of the hook? I'd like to differentiate between new product quantities that were set via a new order and those that were manually updated in the admin panel.

thanks!